# Estimating a higher-oder IRT model in R

Tags: r, item-response-theory, mirt

**Hi everyone**,

I am trying to estimate a higher-order model with the `mirt` package in `R`.

I have already conducted an analysis using a bi-factor structure.

I have 60 items, the first 30 being measured by the first dimension and the second 30 by a second dimension in my model. I know that these two dimensions are strongly correlated (r = .8), which was the motivation to estimate a bi-factor model. However, I would like to compare the bi-factor structure to a model in which both subdimensions are explained by a general factor G (a higher-order IRT model [HO-IRT]).

I have trouble finding the correct model specification to estimate the model. This gives me a bi-factor model.

```
specific <- c(rep(1,30),rep(2,30))

mod <- bfactor(all_data,specific,itemtype = "Rasch")
```

However, the bi-factor model gives me a model with 3 uncorrelated dimensions (one general and two specific). What I am trying to specify is that the two lower tier factors (measured by 30 items each) both load on a general factor, while the lower tier factors are uncorrelated, similar to this article https://doi.org/10.1177/0146621608326423

I am happy if someone could help me out here.

Comment: Hi Nicolas! What do you mean by "... the first 30 being one and the second 30 being a second dimensions of my model." ?

Comment: I have edited the main question, sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. See the link below for an example. https://groups.google.com/g/mirt-package/c/Q6izYN0ab3Y

Comment: Thank you very much. That was what I was looking for!